# Lebesgue measure on interval

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Determine the Lebesgue measure of a set of numbers from the range [0,1] for which there are such decimal increments of $0,1,2,3,\ldots,$  that each of them appears after the decimal point at least once.

Comment: Either the set your are talking about has finite amount of elements or I don't understand the problem very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having no idea what a "decimal increment" is, I find the statement unclear. I think you mean this: Find the measure of the set of numbers  $x\in[0,1]$ such that each digit $0,\dots,9$ appears at least once in the decimal expansion of $x$.

If that's the question the answer is $1$.

**Hint:** It's enough to show that $m(S)=0$, if $S$ is the set of $x$ such that $0$ does *not* appear in the decimal expansion of $x$. (Then the same holds for any other digit in place of $0$, and the  union of ten null sets is a null set...)

Of course a number can have more than one decimal expansion, so the problem is really not well defined. But there are only countably many numbers with more than one expansion (proof?), so we can ignore them.

Ignoring numbers with more than one expansion, the set of numbers that do not have $0$ as the *first* digit is simply $[1/10,1]$. Now figure out what the set of numbers without a zero in the first *two* digits is...